# How to test flyway migration with spring boot?

Tags: spring, integration-testing, flyway

I would ask you how are you testing if migration was succesful.

Scenario:
In first version of entity we have some fields. In next version I'm adding another entity which contains some data from first table. How can I test if this data migrated correctly.

Of course I can check this manually by writing SELECT's etc.

But is there any way to test this in unit/integration test.

**v1**

```
People(
id: Int
name: String
street: String
)
```

**v2**

```
People(
id: Int
name: String
addressId: Int
)

Address(
id: Int
street: String <--- migrated from v1 People table
)
```

Comment: you can add integration tests with retrieve all people entity as object list and check the adress, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes but if database already exists. I need to have multiple instance (one before migration and second aftter). Cause usually if you have integration tests then your import.sql is correct

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by setting Hibernate validation mode. It will achieve a "test" once Flyway finishes its migration. In your application.properties, apply the following change:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

With this, Hibernate will verify that your table complies with your entity definitions. If not, you will get errors of missing information.